# How to get date from day of next week in php

Tags: php, date, getdate

I´d like to print out date from day of week and right now I´m using the following string to get date from monday:

```
$current_dayname = date("l");
echo $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('monday this week'));
```

It works and on monday morning I´ll get the date from monday. Now what I´d like to accomplish is to print out the date from next monday already on saturday. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below:

```
echo $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('monday next week'));
```

This should give you the date of the following Monday.

This will also work:

```
echo $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('monday this week +1 week'));
```